# Routing packages through other nodes in a wireless network

Tags: networking, wifi, routing

I have the following situation:

I have a wireless access point (192.168.42.1), with 3 hosts connected to it:

**Host 1**: 192.168.42.130

**Host 2**: 192.168.42.101

**Host 3**: 192.168.42.58

Is it possible to create a route between any pairs of nodes whose packets exchanged between them necessarily pass through Host 1? (For example: if Host 2 and Host 3 exchange packets, the packets, in addition to passing through the access point, must pass through Host 1 as well). If so, how could I do this?

Best regards,

*Higo*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put Host2 and Host3 on different subnets (so that they will not try to talk to each other directly). For example, Host2=192.168.1.2/24 and Host3=192.168.2.2/24. Then give Host1 addresses on both subnets, like 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1 and set up IP forwarding on Host1 and set up Host2/3 to use the respective .1 addresses as their default route.

If you want to make this really secure, you need to use VLANs on the wireless router to keep these network segments isolated.

Comment: Thank you, DepressedDaniel!

But in this situation the packages would no longer pass through the access point, correct? If so, this situation is undesirable in my case; It is necessary that in addition to Host1, the packets also pass through the access point, before going to their destination.

Comment: Additionally, security, by now, is not an issue, but thank you for the suggestion.